# Live Agent + Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, liveagent, lightning, pre-chat

Is there any standard way of initializing the LIVE AGENT chat from withing Lightning Components in Community Builder.
I have a prechat from within Community builder which is to be used to initialize the chat.

The chat window at user's end open up with below URL, which also cannot be reused due to variation in the session ID everytime

***https://4y3q.la2w1cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=en_US#deployment_id=5721100000000JJ&org_id=00D1100000C1s0t&button_id=5731100000000k0&session_id=791ea201-d098-4201-b6be-80e52316bec1***

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hello Neha, Did you find any resolution for this question....? If yes, Please help on this question...
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135823/facing-issue-with-implementation-of-live-agent-in-lighting-components-csp-issue