# Facing issue with Implementation of Live Agent in Lightning Components: CSP Issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, liveagent

I am facing issue while implementing Live Agent with Lightning Components(Lockerservice disabled). Below are the details required. Here, I am facing issue with initializing LiveAgent.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

**Component Markup:**

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/ChartJs/deployment.js" />

<img id="liveagent_button_online_57328000000TNGq" 
     style="display: none; border: 0px none; cursor: pointer" 
     onclick="liveagent.startChat('57328000000TNGq')" 
     src="/resource/LiveChatOL_Small" />
<img id="liveagent_button_offline_57328000000TNGq" 
     style="display: none; border: 0px none; " 
     src="/resource/LiveChatOff_Small" />
<ui:button label="Show Live Agent" press="{!c.ini}"/>
```

**Component.js:**

```
({
ini : function (component,event,helper){
    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
    console.log('***Live Agent init:'+JSON.stringify(liveagent));
    window._laq.push(function(){
            console.log('***Live Agent button init:');
            liveagent.showWhenOnline('57328000000TNGq', 
            document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_57328000000TNGq'));

            liveagent.showWhenOffline('57328000000TNGq', 
            document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_57328000000TNGq'));
    });
    console.log('***Live Agent init:'+JSON.stringify(window._laq));
    liveagent.init('https://d.la10.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '57228000000TNGX', '00D280000015In1');
    console.log('***myAction Completes'+liveagent.init('https://d.la10.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '57228000000TNGX', '00D280000015In1'));
}
})
```

Comment: Did you overcome this issue?

Comment: did you find any resolution to this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locker Service for Communities blocks any attempts to include Salesforce Live Agent. Is this a bug?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140139/locker-service-for-communities-blocks-any-attempts-to-include-salesforce-live-ag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old question. Now Salesforce provide OOB snap-in component that can be used.